# jquery function to enable disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcombobox

can anyone help me with my code...i want to do is to to enable disable button if the inputs `textbox` are not empty but in my current code its not working.

i have a `selectbox` that if i select from it the `textbox` will automatically filled but if i select empty the textboxes will be empty.

my problem is my script to enable disable button is not working.

output in my browser:
http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/hey_zps31f4cd60.png.html

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Caraga Region: <select name="region" id="region" onChange="here()"></select>
Municipalities: <select name="town" id="town" onChange="here()"></select>
Unique ID: <select name="uniq_id" id="uniq_id" onChange="here()"></select>
Position: <select name="position" id="position" onChange="here()"></select> <br />
Salary Grade: <select name="salary_grade" id="salary_grade" onChange="here()"></select>
Salary: <select name="salary" id="salary" onChange="here()"></select> <br />
<br />
<br />
Transfer Selected Text to textbox:<br />
<input id="t_region" name="t_region" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_town" name="t_town" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_uniq_id" name="t_uniq_id" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_position" name="t_position" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_salary_grade" name="t_salary_grade" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_salary" name="t_salary" type="text" ><br /><br />

List of Applicants:<br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic1" id="aic1" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 1.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name1" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic2" id="aic2" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 2.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name2" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic3" id="aic3" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 3.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name3" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic4" id="aic4" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 4.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name4" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic5" id="aic5" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 5.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name5" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic6" id="aic6" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 6.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name6" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic7" id="aic7" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 7.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name7" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic8" id="aic8" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 8.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name8" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic9" id="aic9" /><input class="number" placeholder=" 9.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name9" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic10" id="aic10" /><input class="number" placeholder="10.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name10" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic11" id="aic11" /><input class="number" placeholder="11.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name11" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic12" id="aic12" /><input class="number" placeholder="12.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name12" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic13" id="aic13" /><input class="number" placeholder="13.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name13" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic14" id="aic14" /><input class="number" placeholder="14.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name14" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input readonly type="text" class="number" name="aic15" id="aic15" /><input class="number" placeholder="15.)" name="name1" type="text" required id="name15" readonly style="width:50%" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" disabled />
</form>
```

script to enable button if textbox is empty: note its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.number').on('input', function () {
        $('#send').prop("disabled", !$.trim(this.value));
    });

    $('.number').each(function() {
        if ($.trim(this.value).length) {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
            return;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried changeing `this.value` to `$(this).val()`?

Comment: @Nico O i tried that but still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .on event won't fire when you populate the text boxes outside of the browser.  If you are setting the text boxes with code like this upon drop down selection (can't see that part of your code):

```
$('.number').val('foo')
```

Then you need to add a trigger event like this:

```
$('.number').val('foo').trigger('input');
```

By adding the trigger when you populate the inputs your existing code should work.  See this slightly [altered example](http://jsfiddle.net/3cACN/6/) of your code.  Be sure to run it after it loads for the first time.

Comment: they are readyonly because i have a functionthat when i select in the select box the textboxes will automatically filled with names

Comment: ah ok sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: @user3352395 fixed my existing post...hope this helps now!

Comment: .trigger('input'); is the key to my problem :D

Answer (score 2):

The `input` event will not fire if you set the value of the text box with code.  In your change event, after you populate a text box, you should check if all the text boxes have a value, and then enable/disable the button.

```
function here() {
    // ... current code that populates the text boxes ...


    var disableBtn = false;
    // check if all text boxes have a value
    $('.number').each(function(i,el) {
        if (!$.trim($(el).val()).length) {
            disableBtn = true;
        }
    });

    $('#send').prop("disabled", disableBtn);
}
```

Comment: I'am not too sure with `removeProp`. The docs say: "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead." I've created an ugly jsfiddle with jquer 1.8, and it only needs to set `.prop()` http://jsfiddle.net/YpG3X/

Comment: removed removeProp. nice catch.

Comment: code wont work...my textboxes are readyonly because i have a function that when i select in the select box the textboxes will automatically filled with names...currently all the answers are not working O.o

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Anyway, you are talking about **"unable"** the button, but I think you meant **"enable"** which means the opossite to disabled, am I correct?